# Amazon Advertising API get Node's products

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-product-api

I'm creating e-commerce shop with Amazon API integration.
The problem I faced with is I cannot get items from specific node.
So I've tried many ways to do that, last one was something like this:

```
$fields = array();
$fields['AssociateTag'] = "ItemSearch";
$fields['Condition'] = 'All';
$fields['Operation'] = 'ItemSearch';
$fields['Version'] = '2013-08-01';
$fields['BrowseNode'] = $catId;
$fields['ResponseGroup'] = "Images,ItemAttributes,Offers";
$fields['Service'] = 'AWSECommerceService';
$fields['Timestamp'] = gmdate('Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z');
$fields['AWSAccessKeyId'] = $this->accessKey;
```

After that call I have the output:

```
public 'Items' => 
    object(SimpleXMLElement)[150]
      public 'Request' => 
        object(SimpleXMLElement)[139]
          public 'IsValid' => string 'True' (length=4)
          public 'ItemSearchRequest' => 
            object(SimpleXMLElement)[138]
              public 'BrowseNode' => string '1289481011' (length=10)
              public 'Condition' => string 'All' (length=3)
              public 'ResponseGroup' => 
                array (size=3)
                  0 => string 'Images' (length=6)
                  1 => string 'ItemAttributes' (length=14)
                  2 => string 'Offers' (length=6)
```

So I can see my request, but no items were returned to me.

By the way, ItemLookup, ItemSearch with keywords and BrowseNode operations work just fine.
What can I do to get items from node with spicific ID without using keywords?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what happened. I didn't set SearchIndex when I point BrowseNode ID.
So there was no result.